# How to actually change the shard key for MongoDB Sharded collection (4.2)

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 4.2 supposedly allows you to change the shard key for a collection according to the documents here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#update-shard-key

However, the documentation says you need to run an update operation to change the documents shard key.  It doesn't give an example of how to do this.  I know how to run an update operation to update the contents of the documents.  Is there some flag that you need to provide to update operation to change it's shard key instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is talking about changing shard key *values* within documents, not changing the actual collection's shard key definition (that's still not supported).

Answer (score 1):

No flag needed.

If you tried modifying a field that was included in shard key pre-4.2, you should've received an error.

If you issue the same update on 4.2, the update simply works.

If you are using a compound shard key, you need to include all fields comprising the shard key into the find condition as stated in the manual.